PowerShell Inhertiance: What is the purpose of having empty constructor in Base class?
I am trying to understand the concept of Class Inheritance in PowerShell. I almost get everything works, just need someone to explain the error and the empty constructor that I accidentally found out.
I define a base class.

class Human {
    [string]$name
    [string]$gender

    Human(){}  # Comment out this line and hit error
    Human($name, $gender)
    {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.gender = $gender
    }

    [void]Speak()
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "I am a human"
    }
}

Define Teacher class derived from Human class.
class Teacher : Human {
    # Don't need to repeat $name & $gender if inherit from Human class

    # Introduce new class property -> $subject
    [string]$subject

    Teacher($name, $gender, $subject)
    {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.gender = $gender
        $this.subject = $subject
    }

    # Overrides Speak() method in Human class
    [void]Speak()
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "I am a $($this.subject) teacher"
    }
}

$t1 = [Teacher]::new("Steven", 'Male', 'English')
$t1
$t1.Speak()

Instance $t1 works just fine with following output.
subject name   gender
------- ----   ------
English Steven Male

I am a English teacher

I will get following output with an error message if comment out the Human(){} in Human class. Though PowerShell still print output for $t1 and $t1.Speak(). For the record, I am using PowerShell 7.4.2 on VS Code. And here is my reference for class inheritance.
MethodException: 
Line |
   8 |      {
     |      ~
     | Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "0".


The error you're seeing when removing the empty constructor is because you're missing the arguments being passed to base class constructor, $name and $gender in this case:
class Teacher : Human {
    [string] $subject

    Teacher($name, $gender, $subject) : base($name, $gender) {
        # assignments of `.name` and `.gender` can be omitted here
        # as the base `.ctor` is already taken care of those
        $this.subject = $subject
    }

    [void] Speak() {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "I am a $($this.subject) teacher"
    }
}

Inheritance is well documented in about_Classes_Inheritance however there isn't much focus in the base keyword and, to my knowledge, there is no PowerShell documentation that focuses on this keyword specifically. However, there is one for c#: base (C# Reference).
There are of course some differences between both languages, i.e. examples taken from the linked doc:
public DerivedClass(int i) : base(i)

Can be very similarly translated:
DerivedClass([int] $i) : base($i)

However when calling a base class method:
public override void GetInfo()
{
    // Calling the base class GetInfo method:
    base.GetInfo();
    // ...
}

There is no $base special variable to reference the base class, in PowerShell the translation of the above would be:
[void] GetInfo() {
    # Calling the base class GetInfo method:
    ([Person] $this).GetInfo();
    # ...
}


TQ @'Santiago Squarzan'. It works now. I just notice that I can omit the $this.name and $this.gender since they are inherited from Human class. Is this idea valid?

it sure is and thats my bad cause I missed that too! good catch @OngK.S !

Basically:
By adding a Overloaded Constructor in the Base Class, the Derived Class attempts to inherit and overload the Default Constructor of the Base Class.
But there is no Default Constructor to inherit.
Thus the error.
tl;dr: always write a Default Constructor.
